# Cannot make newline character work in XSLT to Excel

Tags: excel, xslt, transform, newline, ampersand

I have an XSLT file to transform an XML to output XML containing Excel tags like Row, Cell, etc.

The XSLT file has the below line:

```
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />
```

I need to display a multiline text in a single Excel cell, and I am trying to create that cell via this template:

```
<Cell>
  <Data ss:Type="String">
    <xsl:value-of select="First Line" />
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Second Line" />
  </Data>
</Cell>
```

I am trying to obtain a literal character entity in my output, like so:

```
<Cell>
  <Data ss:Type="String">First Line&#10;Second Line</Data>
</Cell>
```

But instead, the output XML comes out to be:

```
<Cell>
  <Data ss:Type="String">First Line&amp;#10;Second Line</Data>
</Cell>
```

Consequently, when I save the output XML as .xls and open it in Excel 365, the text is NOT multiline. Instead, the corresponding cell contains the lieral string:

> First Line&#10;Second Line

I also tried the below, but it doesn't work, either:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&]]></xsl:text>
```

Nor does this work:

```
<xsl:text>&amp;#</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="10" />
<xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
```

How can I obtain the result I need?

I am using Office 365 and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: So you are trying to write a template that emits a character entity (`&#10;`) into the transformed output?

Comment: Exactly. But it just comes out as &amp;x10; instead of &x10;

Comment: Try `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>`? Not clear what the expected result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clarified that you are trying to emit XML text that contains a numeric character entity, specifically `&#10;`.  The first example you presented is a correct approach, and it works for me, contrary to your claim.

For example, processing this XML:

```
<cell/>
```

according to this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="cell">
    <cell>
      <xsl:value-of select="'First Line'"/>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="'Second Line'"/>
    </cell>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

via `xsltproc` produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cell>First Line&#10;Second Line</cell>
```

, which is the form you are looking for, as I understand it.  In particular, a text field with `disable-output-escaping="yes"` is an appropriate method for emitting literal text that has the form of markup.

I am inclined to doubt that the specific approach you say you tried first indeed produced the output that you claim it did.  That's what you should get *without* `disable-output-escaping`, so perhaps you omitted that attribute or misspelled it in your actual test.  If you included it exactly as shown and got the output you present, then I'm inclined to think that your XSLT processor is broken.

Comment: Thankyou very very much. It helped. I was concatenating 'First Line', <text>'&amp;#10;'</text> and 'Second line' into a variable. so my variable had the value 'First Line&#10;Second Line' which is exactly what I needed. But while writing that variable sing <value-of> I didn't specify disable-output-escaping inside <value-of> so it was output as 'First Line&amp;#10;Second Line'.